# Convert equations to Python language

Tags: python

How can I convert this equation to Python code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5BUC.png)

Comment: What is the problem? What did you try?

Comment: Can you please add little more description what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have this equation and I need to convert it into the variable python code

Comment: d=[0.38C(1-g/C)2]/[1-(g/C)(X)]+173X2[(X-1)+[(X-1)2 + (16X/C)]1/2]

Comment: I have the value of C,g and X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can need to learn about operator precedence and associativity in Programming Languages. That way you can strengthen your understanding of how to perform complex calculations in Python. 

Apart from that try to break the problem into smaller subproblems and combine the smaller subproblems to generate solution for the larger problem.

[0.38C(1-g/C)2] = (0.38 * C) * (1 - (g/C) * 2)  
[1-(g/C)(X)]    = (1 - (g/C) * X)  
173X2           = 173 * 2  
[(X-1)+[(X-1)2 + (16X/C)]1/2] = ((X-1)+((X-1)*2 + (16*X/C))* 1/2)


Now put all values in the equation:  
"d=[0.38C(1-g/C)2]/[1-(g/C)(X)]+173X2[(X-1)+[(X-1)2 + (16X/C)]1/2]"   


    d = (((0.38 * C)*(1 - (g/c)) * 2 ) / (1 - (g/C) * X)) + 172 * 2 *((X-1) +((X-1)+((X-1)*2 + (16*X/C))* 1/2)
```